# VStack inside NavigationLink

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I am trying to VStack an Image and a Text inside a NavigationLink.

This is my code:

```
NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()){
    Circle()
        .fill(Color.green)
        .frame(width: 50, height:50)
        .overlay(Image(systemName: "arrow.up"))
    Text("Send")
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
}
```

```
VStack {
if item.title == "Send"{
    NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()) {
        VStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.green)
                .frame(width: 50, height:50)
                .overlay(Image(systemName: "arrow.up"))
            Text("Send")
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
        }
    }
}}
```

If I try to VStack inside the NavigationLink then nothing would compile.
 If I try to VStack everything, then the image and the text would still show next to each other.
I am trying to achieve the right example:

[image]

Comment: The braces (curly brackets) in your second code sample are unbalanced: there are 4 opening braces `{`, but only 3 closing braces `}`. Could it be that the outer `VStack` includes more views?

Comment: yes it should be 4, but the issue still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("new View")) {
                ZStack {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.green.opacity(0.7))
                        .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                    
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                            .renderingMode(.template)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                        Text("send")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to replicate your issue. The following compiles and displayed as desired.

```
VStack {
    NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()) {
        VStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.green)
                .frame(width: 50, height:50)
                .overlay(Image(systemName: "arrow.up"))
            Text("Send")
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I try this, I get an error:
The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time

Comment: Are you sure you're copying and pasting the code? I'm confident you must have messed up a bracket in another section of the code.